# Delete a files in folder which does not have name XYZ

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder C:\remote and it has two folders each A and B and each of those contain mutiple folders inside it xyc, dsx, axyz etc, i want to delete subfolder anything which does not have name xyz.

Ant help would be great

```
set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks" 
cd /d %folder% 
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('migrate') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

Comment: here is my script which wont work I am trying to delete all folders which are not named migrate

Comment: set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('migrate') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)

Comment: please do not paste code to comments. Edit your question instead (I did it for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
@echo off
set PROCESS_DIR=C:\Users\plamb\Desktop\tmp
set TO_RETAIN=xyz

for /d %%d in (%PROCESS_DIR%\*) do (
    echo Processing directory: %%d
    for /d %%f in (%%d\*) do (
        if not "%%f" == "%%d\%TO_RETAIN%" (
            echo Deleting sub-directory: %%f
            rd %%f /s /q
        )

        if "%%f" == "%%d\%TO_RETAIN%" (
            echo Retaining sub-directory: %%f
        )
    )
)
set PROCESS_DIR=
set TO_RETAIN=
@echo on
```

This looks for directories in the current directory, then checks immediate subdirectories of these directories and deletes any subfolder NOT called xyz (case sensitive).

Run it in your C:\remote directory. And it will remove the directories you wish below that level. Change xyz to whatever you wish.

Comment: "not working" is not a very helpful description. What does it do and how does that differ from your expectations?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some debugging to show you what it's doing on standard out. It does work. I've tested it.

Comment: Sorry I tried below code and it runs but does nothing

Comment: I've edited it again to even allow for parameterization of the root directory and the sub directory to remove. If you want it to do it recursively, then this doesn't do that. You may have to add some quotation marks to cater for spaces in paths, but should work other than that.

Comment: echo off
set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks"
cd /d %folder%
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    echo Processing directory: %%d
    for /d %%f in (%%d\*) do (
        if "%%f" == "%%d\migrate" (
            echo Deleting sub-directory: %%f
            rd %%f /s /q
        )

        if not "%%f" == "%%d\migrate" (
            echo Retaining sub-directory: %%f
        )
    )
)
echo on

Comment: echo off
set PROCESS_DIR="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks"
set TO_REMOVE=migrate

for /d %%d in (%PROCESS_DIR%\*) do (
    echo Processing directory: %%d
    for /d %%f in (%%d\*) do (
        if "%%f" == "%%d\xyz" (
            echo Deleting sub-directory: %%f
            rd %%f /s /q
        )

        if not "%%f" == "%%d\%TO_REMOVE%" (
            echo Retaining sub-directory: %%f
        )
    )
)
set PROCESS_DIR=
set TO_REMOVE=
echo on

Comment: Create a batch file from the code I've supplied above. Change the PROCESS_DIR variable to the folder you wish it to look in (C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks). Change the TO_REMOVE variable to migrate. It will then look for subfolders of the migrate folder, look at each subdirectory of each of those folders and remove the ones called migrate.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear I want to delete all folder other than migrate, just keep migrate and delete other folders

Comment: Ok. Done. Should do what you require now.

Comment: Dont know what i am doing wrong create a bat file below and it dosent do anything echo off
set PROCESS_DIR=C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks
set TO_RETAIN=migrate

for /d %%d in (%PROCESS_DIR%\*) do (
    echo Processing directory: %%d
    for /d %%f in (%%d\*) do (
        if not "%%f" == "%%d\%TO_RETAIN%" (
            echo Deleting sub-directory: %%f
            rd %%f /s /q
        )

        if "%%f" == "%%d\%TO_RETAIN%" (
            echo Retaining sub-directory: %%f
        )
    )
)
set PROCESS_DIR=
set TO_RETAIN=
echo on

Comment: 3 steps. A - create a batch file and paste in the code I've supplied above. B - edit the PROCESS_DIR variable to be the root folder you wish to interrogate. C - edit the TO_RETAIN variable to specify the subfolder you wish to keep. Then just run the batch file and see what it outputs on the command line in terms of removal and retention. Don't know how else to tell you what to do. It should be really simple.

Comment: Yes, that's what you said above. You have a folder with subfolders A, B, etc and you wanted to delete subfolders inside those ones (root\A\dir1, root\A\dir2, root\B\dir1, etc). Glad you finally got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

here is below code which is not working, it runs but does not do anything

@echo off
set PROCESS_DIR=C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks
set TO_RETAIN=migrate

for /d %%d in (%PROCESS_DIR%*) do (
    echo Processing directory: %%d
    for /d %%f in (%%d*) do (
        if not "%%f" == "%%d\%TO_RETAIN%" (
            echo Deleting sub-directory: %%f
            rd %%f /s /q
        )

```
    if "%%f" == "%%d\%TO_RETAIN%" (
        echo Retaining sub-directory: %%f
    )
)
```

)
set PROCESS_DIR=
set TO_RETAIN=
@echo on

Answer (score 0):

Below code works , but it deletes everything

set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)

Answer (score 0):

This code below retain folders that have the `%retain%` value *in any part* of the name:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "retain=migrate"
set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks" 
cd /d %folder% 
for /D %%i in (*) do (
   set "folder=%%i"
   if "!folder:%retain%=!" equ "%%i" rmdir "%%i" /s/q
)
```

And this one retain just the one named `%retain%`:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "retain=migrate"
set folder="C:\Users\rmakkena\AppData\Roaming\TabMigrate\10.212.38.15\TBM\workbooks" 
cd /d %folder% 
for /D %%i in (*) do (
   if /I "%%i" neq "%retain%" rmdir "%%i" /s/q
)
```